# why my header render every time already use React.memo?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-hooks

could you please tell me `why my header render every time already use React.memo ?` I have two section `my app and user` when I am navigation from `my apps` to `user` `header` re-render why ?

here is my code

https://codesandbox.io/s/fancy-microservice-gl734?file=/src/header.js

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";

const Header = React.memo(function() {
  console.log("HeaderHeaderHeaderHeaderHeader");

  return <div>header</div>;
});

export default withRouter(Header);
```

when you run application it shows `apps` but when you are click `user` it show `user` page ..**see console header is rerender**

I tried with `pure component` still same issue

```
import React, { PureComponent } from "react";

class Header extends PureComponent {
  render() {
    console.log("HeaderHeaderHeaderHeader");
    return <div>header</div>;
  }
}

export default Header;
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/fancy-microservice-gl734?file=/src/test.js:0-202

Comment: Is this causing a problem for you? React rerenders frequently as states change.

Comment: my problem to stop extra re-redering..!! where state is changed?

Comment: But why is rerendering a problem? That's a very normal thing in React and part of the core reason it exists. So unless the rerenders are actually causing errors for you, then I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: rerender create a issue in performance,..

Comment: It is a performance issue only when you have measured it. react-dev-tools profiler tells you the reason  of rerender. You can have a look at that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, what you're trying to do is not how React works.

`React.memo` allows you to avoid running a child's render function if the parent component is rendering that child with the same props. If [reconciliation](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html#elements-of-different-types) replaces the *parent* with a new component, the new parent is not going to reuse the same memoized component even if it's rendering the same child as the last parent.

So in the case of your `react-router`, when you switch routes, every component will be re-rendered. The DOM may avoid unnecessary updates still, but your render functions will still get invoked.

If you pull the `<Header/>` component out higher up in the tree, you may be able to avoid your re-renders.